# Framerate drop when pressing the 'period' key

Tags: chivalry-medieval-warfare

Every time I press the 'period' key, the frame rate drops to red (monitored by toggling 'stat fps' in the console).  Before you boggle about my use of 'period', I use a dvorak keyboard and 'period' is where the 'e' key is.  In any case, pressing the 'period' key causes this drop, what's the deal yo?

Comment: Is the key bound to anything in the game?

Comment: It's bound to 'move forward'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hah, I figured it out.  Posting here in case anyone else has the same issue.

The UDKGame.ini file ..\Documents\my games\Chivalry Medieval Warfare\UDKGame\Config had this line in it:

```
Bindings=(Name="Period",SecondaryKey=,Command="GBA_MoveForward;RECOMPILESHADERS CHANGED",Control=False,Shift=False,Alt=False,bIgnoreCtrl=False,bIgnoreShift=False,bIgnoreAlt=False,Flag="KBFlag_Movement",FriendlyName="MoveForward")
```

Removed the 'RECOMPILESHADERS CHANGED' part and now it doesn't do that anymore.  Hurray for hidden bindings!